# Visual Studio 2019 Error "basepath argument is not fully qualified"

Tags: visual-studio

After upgrading my C++ DLL project from VS2017 to VS2019 I try to launch it with the debug options "Command" specifying a local .exe and "Working Directory".

Trying to start it in the debugger doesn't work because VS reports the error "Basepath argument is not fully qualified".

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had some invalid characters in the both paths, which were probably invisible, but by using the "Browse..." function in the Options dialog for these options I could fix it.